# Woocommerce - Include custom user meta in order 'filter by registered customer' Ajax search

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to include a users custom meta named 'sageaccountnumber' within the 'filter by registered customer' section of the WooCommerce orders list as shown below:

[image]

I already have the custom meta field named 'sageaccountnumber' working with the following PHP code:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'sab_save_sageaccount_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'sab_save_sageaccount_user_profile_fields' );
function sab_save_sageaccount_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'sageaccountnumber', $_POST['sageaccountnumber'] );
}
```

When searching for a registered customer I would like to include the user meta 'sageaccountnumber' within the search and display matching results.

I understand this uses AJAX within the file class-wc-ajax.php. This is the function in question: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_AJAX::json_search_customers

I do not know alot about AJAX and I have not been able to find a way to include a custom user meta value in this search. I have not found anyone else doing this.

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After getting lost with trying to understand the class-wc-ajax.php file, I completely missed a more obvious and simple solution. Here is the code I am using which works perfectly. I hope this helps others looking for similar solution.

This filter-hook allows you to add an additional meta_query to the existing search parameters. This will also allow your custom user meta to display in AJAX searches from the Orders & Subscriptions pages.

If you have a custom meta field setup for your users, simply change 'sageaccountnumber' to the name of your meta and it will be included in the AJAX search results.

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_customer_search_customers', 'sab_sageaccount_order_subscription_search', 10, 4);
function sab_sageaccount_order_subscription_search ($filter, $term, $limit, $type){
    if ($type == 'meta_query'){ $filter['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'sageaccountnumber', 'value' => $term, 'compare' => 'LIKE');
    }
    return $filter;
}
```

If you need to include the custom meta field in the normal users search, you can use the following code, again changing 'sageaccountnumber' to your custom meta name.

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'sab_sageaccount_user_search'  );
function sab_sageaccount_user_search( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $pagenow;

    if (is_admin() && 'users.php' == $pagenow) {
        if( empty($_REQUEST['s']) ){return;}
        $query->query_fields = 'DISTINCT '.$query->query_fields;
        $query->query_from .= ' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->usermeta.' ON '.$wpdb->usermeta.'.user_id = '.$wpdb->users.'.ID';
        $query->query_where = "WHERE 1=1 AND (user_login LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['s']."%' OR ID = '".$_REQUEST['s']."' OR (meta_value LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['s']."%' AND meta_key = 'sageaccountnumber'))";
    }
    return $query;
}
```